# UITableViewHeader that does not scroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have a TableViewController which should have a "floating" header at the top of the table view which should ***not*** scroll with the content.

Is there a way to achieve this using a UITableViewController (I know this could be done with nested a Tableview inside a plain `UIViewController` but I would prefer to have a `UITableViewController` as the main ViewController so I can use the benefits of Storyboard TableView-Goodies.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want the table view controller be the main view controller?

Comment: I haven't had the pleasure of working with Storyboards yet, but what happens if you use a plain `UIViewController` and implement the `UITableViewDelegate` and `-Datasource` protocols. Can you then still use the benefits of Storyboard TableView-Goodies?

Comment: I don't work with IB or storyboards at all and if these are unable to handle a special (your own) UIViewController subclass with a UITableViewController as child view controller I know (one more) good reason why I don't. But I'm sure that's not case.

Comment: @Kai `so I can use the benefits of Storyboard TableView-Goodies.`, which means prototype cells and or having a static table view. This is not possible otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Make a nib with a `UITableViewController` or a subclass of it and simply rearrange the table view to make room for the header view. A table view controller with a slightly different layout and more views is still a table view controller.

Comment: The Tableview controller has to be in the storyboard not in a nib, otherwise I can't benefit from the mentioned "Storyboard-benefits"

Comment: Same thing. Toss a table view controller onto the storyboard surface. I think you can still move the table view around. If you can't, use a view controller, change its class to `UITableViewController`, add a table view and wire it up as usual.

Answer (score -2):

It might be considered a *hack*, but this seems to do the job! (tested with the default Master-Detail project template)

First change the type of the MasterViewController to a `UIViewController` and add the protocol references for the delegate and datasource. Also add an `IBOutlet` for a `UITableView`.

```
@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

Next, wire up that `IBOutlet` to the `UITableView` in the Storyboard editor.

Now add the following code to `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
UILabel *header = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
header.text = @"HEADER";
header.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[mainView addSubview:header];
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 440);
[mainView addSubview:self.tableView];
self.view = mainView;
```

Comment: While this seems to work I get the following error as soon as I add static table cells: `2012-08-22 15:28:11.674 test[45894:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MasterViewController 0xe31ee70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key staticDataSource.'`